# How to scroll Thumbnail image Buttons horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
     <div id="pxs_container" class="pxs_container">
<div class="pxs_slider_wrapper">
                <ul class="pxs_slider">
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>

                </ul>


<ul class="pxs_thumbnails">
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"></li>


                </ul>

                        </div></div>
```

In this Demo, You can see there's px_slider and px_thumbnails. in this slider, when i multiply the slider images, it shows all the thumbnail images in the page. I need to show only 5 thumbnail images and all thumb images must scroll left and right. And when i click thumb image, it must scroll to middle.

how to change this code.

[My Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/YHAYj/7/)

Comment: I see only black screen

Comment: i use this fiddle to show the code. but its not animating in the fiddle.

Comment: thats because the images are missing, add the absolute path for all the images on ur jsfiddle

Comment: Or use http://placehold.it.